# Why the prototype.setName and this.setName can be return different value?

Tags: javascript

There is my code. I am curious what's the different `prototype.setName` and `this.setName`. Why I get a same value of `p2` when I call `p2.setName()`? Thanks.

```
function Person(){
    var name = '';
}

Person.prototype.setName = function (value){
    name = value;
}   
Person.prototype.getName = function (){
    return name;
}

function Sprite(){
    var name = '';
    this.setName = function (value){
        name = value;
    }
    this.getName = function(){
        return name;
    }
}

var p1 = new Person();
p1.setName('p1');
var p2 = new Person();
p2.setName('p2');
console.log(p1.getName()) // p2
console.log(p2.getName()) // p2

var s1 = new Sprite('s1');
s1.setName('s1');
var s2 = new Sprite('s2');
s2.setName('s2');
console.log(s1.getName()); //s1
console.log(s2.getName()); //s2
```

Comment: Because the prototype methods have a different scope (a [global scope](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)!). They're not closures under `Sprite`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that the `name` variable you declared in Person() is only local to that function and is not shared with the prototype functions.

The following is therefore creating a new global variable called `name`.

```
Person.prototype.setName = function (value){
   name = value;
}
```

Since the variable is global it is shared by both `p1` and `p2` (note that if you add `'use strict';` the above causes an exception rather than automatically creating a global).

You should do what @beautifulcoder suggests and use `this` to make the variable a property of the object, like so

```
function Person(){
    this.name = '';
}

Person.prototype.setName = function (value){
    this.name = value;
};   
Person.prototype.getName = function (){
    return this.name;
};
```

Finally, the reason that Sprite() works is because the set and get functions are defined inside the scope of the local `name` variable so they create a closure and use the local `name` rather than creating a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot `this`:

```
Person.prototype.setName = function (value){
    this.name = value;
}   
Person.prototype.getName = function (){
    return this.name;
}
```

It's a confusing design pattern.